# Replace prefixed names with URIs in SPARQL Query which has no Prefixes

Tags: java, sparql, jena

I get a SPARQL query string from a service which looks like the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM { ?s owl:sameAs ?p }
```

If I try to parse this with the `QueryFactory` class I get the `Unresolved Prefixed Name Exception` which totally makes sense.

I have a properties file which maps the [predefined namespace prefixes](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?nsdecl).

For now I have a workaround which looks like the following:

```
Iterator<String> it = prefixConfig.getKeys();
String prefixes = "";
while(it.hasNext()) {
    String p = it.next();
    prefixes += "PREFIX " + p + ":<" + prefixConfig.getString(p) + "> ";
}

Query q = QueryFactory.create(prefixes + query);
it = prefixConfig.getKeys();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    String p = it.next();
    q.getPrefixMapping().removeNsPrefix(p);
}

query = q.toString();
```

This works but I am not happy at all with this *solution*, so my question is:

Is there a good way to either replace the prefixes in the SPARQL query string or to only add the relevant prefixes?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I don't know whether this will work or not, so I'm not posting it as an answer, but QueryFactory#create() will make a query with no parsing, and will return a Query which has a setPrefixMapping() method, by which you might be able to set the prefixes, and then perhaps parse the query string afterward.

Comment: Well, but i need either to parse the query string for the prefixes and then add the needed prefixes or add all prefixes and simply do the same :/ 
But i think i will go with the parsing for now, as it is a better way.

Comment: as I said, I'm not sure whether it provides an answer or not.  But you not be able to build the prefix mapping, and get jena to turn it into the right kind of string for you, which would remove any possible errors in creating it by hand

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String replacePrefixes(String query, PrefixMapping pmap){
    /* With Prologue and the parse method, 
     * the queryString gets parsed without an error
     */
    Prologue prog = new Prologue();
    prog.setPrefixMapping(pmap);
    Query q = QueryFactory.parse(new Query(prog), query, null, null);
    //Set Prefix Mapping
    q.setPrefixMapping(pmap);
    //remove PrefixMapping so the prefixes will get replaced by the full uris
    q.setPrefixMapping(null);       
    return q.serialize();
}
```

This works for me :)